# Batch convert files while retaining the name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, calibre

I want to use the following command to convert ebooks from epub format to mobi format:
`calibre-convert books/*.epub books/*.mobi`

but i want to retain the same file name for all the files.
So book1.epub will create book1.mobi 
book2.epub will create book2.mobi after conversion.
is this doable in the command line? or do i have to write a bash script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
( cd books && for file in *.epub; do calibre-convert "$file" "${file%epub}mobi"; done )
```

The main trick here is `${file%epub}` which means "`$file` with `epub` at the end removed". This way `${file%epub}mobi` translates the extension.

A subshell (`(…)`) is used so

- the current working directory of the main shell stays intact
- and the `file` variable in the main shell doesn't change.

Any directory that matches `*.epub` in `books/` will be passed to `calibre-convert` as well. It's up to the tool what it will do with the directory. You probably have no such directory there; but if you do, be warned.

<sub>Note: I don't know `calibre-convert` at all; the syntax in my command is simply derived from your command.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wish I could up vote it, but I don't have enough reputations .

Comment: Does the sub-shell just avoid having the `cd` be permanent?

Comment: Do I have to add anything to make the command work recursively on sub folders?  
                    find ~/book -name '*.epub'  -exec  ...........?

Comment: @Xen2050 My first try was without the subshell. Then I realized the command ends elsewhere, so I added a subshell just to fix it. I'm aware one can do this entirely without `cd` (`for file in books/*.epub; …`), no immediate need for a subshell then. But there's another issue when without a subshell (see the edited answer) so I think this subshell is a good idea.

Comment: @Tlink It's possible to do this recursively with `find` or with `**` (after `shopt -s globstar` in Bash). Formal note though: the example in your question is not recursive and my answer keeps things this way. Substantially changing the question after any answer is published (and upvoted, and even accepted by you) is not a good practice here. In my opinion a separate question will be good, where you explicitly ask for a recursive solution (maybe link to this question to provide context, but even then the new question should be standalone).

Comment: agreed, only issue is because of reputation level, there's a limit to the number of questions I can post in a certain time period.

Comment: @Tlink you should be accepting the answer anyway, instead of merely upvoting it

Comment: @Tlink OK then. A recursive approach: `( shopt -s globstar && for file in books/**/*.epub; do calibre-convert "$file" "${file%epub}mobi"; done )`

Comment: `push books` would be better, and a `pop` could be appended.

Comment: @jpmc26 can you elaborate? not sure I understand what you mean.